# Overwrite struct fields with values from other "partial" struct

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I'm playing around with creating a CRUD API. Please forgive the OOP approach in Go where it might not be smart. I have a struct that I want to partially update via a PATCH endpoint.

```
type Book struct {
  Id        uuid.UUID  `json:"id"`
  Author    uuid.UUID  `json:"author"`
  Title     string     `json:"title"`
  IsPublic  bool       `json:"isPublic"`
  CreatedAt time.Time  `json:"createdAt"`
  UpdatedAt *time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
  DeletedAt *time.Time `json:"deletedAt"`
}
```

I've defined a second struct with the updatable properties for a book.

```
type PatchBookDto struct {
  Author   *uuid.UUID
  Title    *string
  IsPublic *bool
}
```

In both structs I'm using (possibly abusing?) the pointer properties to mimic optional parameters. What I would like to achieve is to override a book with any given properties in the PatchBookDto. This is my attempt so far:

```
var book models.Book // Is taken from an array of books
var dto dtos.PatchBookDto

if err := c.BindJSON(&dto); err != nil {
    // Abort
}

dtoTypeInfo := reflect.TypeOf(&dto).Elem()

for i := 0; i < dtoTypeInfo.NumField(); i++ {
    dtoField := dtoTypeInfo.Field(i)
    bookField := reflect.ValueOf(&book).Elem().FieldByName(dtoField.Name)

    if bookField.IsValid() && bookField.CanSet() {

        dtoValue := reflect.ValueOf(dto).Field(i)

        if dtoValue.Interface() == reflect.Zero(dtoValue.Type()).Interface() {
            continue
        }

        if dtoField.Type.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            if dtoValue.Elem().Type().AssignableTo(bookField.Type()) {
                bookField.Set(dtoValue.Elem())
            } else {
                // Abort
            }
        }

        convertedValue := dtoValue.Convert(bookField.Type())
        bookField.Set(convertedValue)
    }
}
```

When I test this, I get a `reflect.Value.Convert: value of type *string cannot be converted to type string` error.

Anyone have any idea what I can improve here to get what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you intended to put the panicking line in an else block for `if dtoField.Type.Kind() == reflect.Ptr`.

An alternative is to indirect pointers and then set the value.

```
for i := 0; i < dtoTypeInfo.NumField(); i++ {
    dtoField := dtoTypeInfo.Field(i)
    bookField := reflect.ValueOf(&book).Elem().FieldByName(dtoField.Name)
    if bookField.IsValid() && bookField.CanSet() {
        dtoValue := reflect.ValueOf(dto).Field(i)
        if dtoValue.Interface() == reflect.Zero(dtoValue.Type()).Interface() {
            continue
        }
        dtoValue = reflect.Indirect(dtoValue)
        convertedValue := dtoValue.Convert(bookField.Type())
        bookField.Set(convertedValue)
    }
}
```